# C++ how to check if among N objects some of them are equal

Tags: c++

I have some C++ objects and I would like to check if some of them are equal.

```
bool IsEqual(const Board& b)
{
    if( b.From() != from_ )
        return false;

    if (b.To() != to_ )
        return false;

    if( b.Selection() != selection_ )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

My objects consist of some integers ( from_, to_, selection_) and the class offers the IsEqual method to compare two objects.

calling `obj1.IsEqual(obj2)` returns true if both objects have the same values.

However how do I compare N objects? Is it possible to `push_back` objects to an `std::vector<Board>` and use `std::unique`?

Comment: Try `A.IsEqual(B) ` in a loop

Comment: Do you just want to check whether some are equal or do you also want to know which ones?

Comment: I don't care which are equal. Just want to be sure that there are no duplicates for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to push_back objects to an std::vector and use std::unique?

Yes it is possible, but that would require you to sort your vector first and then use `std::unique` using the same criteria as you used for sort. Note `std::sort` and `std::unqiue` require strict weak ordering as described in [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept. Your `IsEqual` function does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: What needs to be done in IsEqual in order to satisfy the concept?

Comment: @cateof usually it is implemented as less than comparison, not equal that you have.

Comment: @cateof this should be a good start: http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/

Answer (score 3):

Put the objects in a set. After you're done the set will contain only unique objects.

You can choose between `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`, depending on how many objects you have and the cost of the compare function.

`std::set` requires a compare function (`operator<`). O(N*logN) complexity.

`std::unordered_set` requires a hash and equality functions (`std::equal_to` taking 2 const references to your object and `std::hash` taking in a const reference to an object). O(N) complexity.

NB. A double-nested loop is going to be O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

NB2. `std::unique` requires the vector to be sorted, as it compares only adjacent elements.

Example compare function:

```
    bool operator< (const Board& b) const {
        if (from_ < b.from_)
            return true;
        if (from_ > b.from_)
            return false;
        if (to_ < b.to_)
            return true;
        if (to_ > b.to_)
            return false;
        if (selection_ < b.selection_)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `std::unordered_set` requires equality as well and `std::hash` needs only one object

Answer (score 1):

If you make an array of objects and then run a simple loop to compare them like this

```
> board[n];

for(int i=0; i<n ; i++)
  for(int j=i; j<n ; j++)
      board[i].Isequal(board[j]);
```

You can always use more efficient algo to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a home cooked code as below:

1. put objects in an array
2. compare each object to the rest of objects in array in the loop

The loop will look like:

```
A[] arr = {a, b, c, d};
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i < arr.length -1 ; i++) {
  for (int j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
     if (arr[i].IsEqual(arr[j])) counter++;
  }
}
printf("There is %d objects that are equal", counter);
```

Comment: The second loop is missing the -1? Shouldn't be arr.length -1 instead of arr.length?

Comment: Lets consider first element `a`, which will be compared to 2, 3, .. and so on to the last one `d`. So the last element needs to be included as well.